# Adjust form elements | CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust form elements but I can't figure out.

Html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    
{% load static %}
    
{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="{% static 'card-js.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="{% static 'card-js.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>


     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
                <!-- Declaração do formulário -->
                <form action="{% url 'payment:checkout' %}" method="post">

                    <div id="user-info">
                        <p><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>, confira abaixo o endereço de entrega:</p>
                        <p>
                            {{ usuario.rua }}, nº {{ usuario.numero }} - {{ usuario.complemento }}<br>
                            {{ usuario.bairro }}<br>
                            {{ usuario.cidade }}/{{ usuario.estado }}<br>
                            CEP: {{ usuario.cep }}

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="shipping-info">
                            <a href="{% url 'payment:address_change' %}">
                                  Desejo alterar o endereço de entrega</a></p>
                        <hr>


                            {% csrf_token %}

                          <div class="form-group">

                              <label for="card-element">Insira as informações do seu cartão de crédito:</label>

                              <div class="card-js" data-icon-colour="#158CBA">
                               <input class="card-number form-control"
                                      name="my-custom-form-field__card-number"
                                      placeholder="Número do cartão"
                                      autocomplete="off"
                                      id="number-cc"
                                      required>
                               <input class="name" id="name-cc"
                                      placeholder="Nome impresso no cartão"
                                      required>
                               <div class="inline-wrapper">
                                  <input class="expiry-month" placeholder="MM" id="month-cc" required>
                                  <input class="expiry-year" placeholder="YY" id="year-cc" required>
                                  <input class="cvc" id="cvc-cc" required>
                                  <select name="parcelas" class="parcela">
                                     <option value="1">1x s/ juros</option>
                                     <option value="2">2x s/ juros</option>
                                     <option value="3">3x s/ juros</option>
                                  </select>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="mytoken" id="token">
                    <input type="hidden" name="myhash" id="hash">

                    <input type="hidden" name="cep" value='{{ usuario.cep }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="rua" value='{{ usuario.rua }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="numero" value='{{ usuario.numero }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="complemento" value='{{ usuario.complemento }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="bairro" value='{{ usuario.bairro }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cidade" value='{{ usuario.cidade }}'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="estado" value='{{ usuario.estado }}'>
                    <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Realizar pagamento">

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}">&#x2190; Voltar ao carrinho</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Resumo do pedido</h3>
                <hr>
                {% for item in cart %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:1"><img class="row-image" src="{{ item.image.url }}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2">{{ item.description|linebreaks }}</div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>R$ {{item.sell_price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <h6>Subtotal: R$ {{ cart.get_total_price|floatformat:2 }}</h6>
                <h6>{{ context.msg|safe }}</h6>
                <h5>Total: R$ {{ context.total|floatformat:2 }}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    // Iniciando a sessão no PagSeguro
    PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('{{ data.session.id }}');
    console.log('Sua sessão é: {{ data.session.id }}');
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/pagseguro.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
.card-js input.card-number{padding-right:48px}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon{height:23px;width:32px;position:absolute;display:block;right:8px;top:7px;background:url(https://cardjs.co.uk/img/cards.png) 0 23px no-repeat;pointer-events:none;opacity:0;-webkit-transition:opacity .15s linear;-moz-transition:opacity .15s linear;-ms-transition:opacity .15s linear;-o-transition:opacity .15s linear;transition:opacity .15s linear}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .show{opacity:1}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.visa{background-position:0 0}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.master-card{background-position:-32px 0}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.american-express{background-position:-64px 0}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.discover{background-position:-96px 0}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.diners{background-position:-128px 0}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper .card-type-icon.jcb{background-position:-160px 0}
.card-js .cvc-container .parcela{width:50%;float:right}
.card-js .cvc-wrapper .parcela{box-sizing:border-box;margin-left:5px}
.card-js .cvc-wrapper .cvc .parcela{display:block;width:100%}
.card-js .expiry-container .parcela{width:50%;float:left}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .parcela{box-sizing:border-box;margin-right:5px}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry .parcela{display:block;width:100%}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry-month .parcela{border-top-right-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0;padding-left:30px}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry-year .parcela{border-top-left-radius:0;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-left:0}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry-month,.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry-year .parcela{display:inline-block}
.card-js .expiry-wrapper .expiry .parcela{padding-left:38px}
.card-js .icon{position:absolute;display:block;width:24px;height:17px;left:8px;top:10px;pointer-events:none}
.card-js .icon.right{right:8px;left:auto}
.card-js .icon.popup{cursor:pointer;pointer-events:auto}
.card-js .icon .svg{fill:#888}
.card-js .icon.popup .svg{fill:#aaa!important}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper,.card-js .name-wrapper{margin-bottom:15px;width:100%}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper,.card-js .cvc-wrapper,.card-js .expiry-wrapper,.card-js .name-wrapper{-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);-ms-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);-o-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.7);position:relative}
.card-js .card-number-wrapper,.card-js .cvc-container,.card-js .expiry-container,.card-js .name-wrapper{display:inline-block}
.card-js::after{content:' ';display:table;clear:both}
.card-js input,.card-js select{color:#676767;font-size:15px;font-weight:300;font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;height:36px;border:1px solid #d9d9d9;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:none;background-color:#FDFDFD;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;-webkit-transition:border-color .15s linear,box-shadow .15s linear;-moz-transition:border-color .15s linear,box-shadow .15s linear;-ms-transition:border-color .15s linear,box-shadow .15s linear;-o-transition:border-color .15s linear,box-shadow .15s linear;transition:border-color .15s linear,box-shadow .15s linear}
.card-js select{-moz-appearance:none;text-indent:.01px;text-overflow:''}
.card-js input[disabled],.card-js select[disabled]{background-color:#eee;color:#555}
.card-js select option[hidden]{color:#ABA9A9}
.card-js input:focus,.card-js select:focus{background-color:#fff;outline:0;border-color:#66afe9;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6)}
.card-js input[readonly=readonly]:not([disabled]),.card-js input[readonly]:not([disabled]){background-color:#fff;cursor:pointer}
.card-js .has-error input,.card-js .has-error input:focus{border-color:#F64B2F;box-shadow:none}
.card-js input.card-number,.card-js input.cvc,.card-js input.name{padding-left:38px;width:100%}
```

What I'd like to do is to include the select option (class 'parcelas') in the same line as expiry-month-year and CVV elements. In the figure below I tried to draw what would be my wish:

[image]

EDIT:
I also replaced the coding above with the full HTML lines.

[image]

Comment: You can wrap up the elements that you want on the same line in a `div` with `display:flex`. Set the width of your liking for the elements that won't grow, and `flex-grow:1` for the element that should occupy the rest of the available space.

Comment: please make a snippet if you can.

Comment: @Will, I tried that but it's not working. CSS: ".parcela{display:flex}" and in HTML: "<div class="parcela">
        <input class="expiry-month" id="month-cc" required>
        <input class="expiry-year" id="year-cc" required>
        <input class="cvc" id="cvc-cc" required>
        <select name="parcelas" class="parcela">
          <option value="1">1x s/ juros</option>
          <option value="2">2x s/ juros</option>
          <option value="3">3x s/ juros</option>
        </select>
           </div>"

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's what I was suggesting in the comments: wrap up the inline inputs in a div like so:

```
<div class="inline-wrapper">
   <input class="expiry-month" placeholder="MM" id="month-cc" required>
   <input class="expiry-year" placeholder="YY" id="year-cc" required>
   <input class="cvc" id="cvc-cc" required>
   <select name="parcelas" class="parcela">
      <option value="1">1x s/ juros</option>
      <option value="2">2x s/ juros</option>
      <option value="3">3x s/ juros</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And style with flex features:

```
.inline-wrapper {
   display: flex;
}
.inline-wrapper input,
.inline-wrapper select {
   flex: 0 0 10%;
}
.inline-wrapper input:nth-child(-n+2) { /* nth-child(-n+2) = first 2 children */
   flex: 1 1 20%;
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/1tckLpyd/

Comment: I forgot to comment that there is a "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>" inside the html. For some reason, the result is not the same as expected. Can you please help me again? There is also a input after the YY field I don't understand why it is appearing...

Comment: Calling your jQuery library won't alter your CSS. `<input class="cvc" id="cvc-cc" required>` is present in your HTML so it naturally appears on your page.

Comment: You should only include relevant code. Your edit is no longer readable to solve your problem. Also, I don't understand what your problem is now.